# TypeError: Cannot read property 'spacing' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting the below error when using react and material UI

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'spacing' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
buttonTeal: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    color:'white',
    backgroundColor: '#009688',
```

And its being rendered by

```
  const classes = useStyles();
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it, I moved the styles into the hook and changed

```
export default withStyles(useStyles)(Hookname);
```

to

```
export default Hookname;
```

and added

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
```

Rather than

```
const useStyles = theme => ({
```